# table view cell shadow not coming

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell, shadow

I need [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AJiR.png) but the [first cell is having no shadow but the second cell gets such shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1trHf.png) not getting the shadow for table view cell.
i have connected the content view of the table view cell with the cell's viewcontroller and did this:

```
import UIKit

class staydetailsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var price: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Content: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var image1: UIImageView!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        Content.layer.masksToBounds = false
        Content.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        Content.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        Content.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 20)
        Content.layer.shadowRadius = 20
        Content.layer.opacity = 1
        Content.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        Content.layer.borderWidth = 1//(except for this nothing else is woking)


    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)


        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Comment: Is `Content` added to the tableViewCell's content view? Does it have a sensible frame?

Comment: yes the content is a view on the cell of the table view @jefflovejapan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `layoutSubviews` here is a code snippet that you can make use of. There is absolutely no need to add view called contentView just to show shadow, every single `UITableViewCell` comes with a `embedded contentView`

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: radius)
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.5, height: 1)
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25
        self.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.cgPath
    }
```

Comment: @ishtyaq-haider-jafri : Am glad I could be of help buddy :) Happy coding :)

Comment: You don't need to implement `layoutSubviews` to do this. The change that Sandeep added that fixed this is `shadowOpacity`, which is 0 by default.

Comment: @jefflovejapan : With all due respect the reason I asked OP to use layout subviews is for two reasons 1. AM not really sure whether awakeFromNib is getting called or not in his case as OP hasn't provided much contextual info 2. When awake from nib gets called view hasn't found its final size so when you configure your shadow path you might end up having wrong bounds :) But layout subviews will solve both problems. OP cant do anything which would prevent layout subviews being called and when layout subviews gets called view has its size figured out so your shadow path configured properly :)

Comment: OP isn't using a shadow path though, only an offset and radius. These are properties on the layer that are independent of the layer's frame and aren't affected by the size of the cell.

Comment: @SandeepBhandari please see now again.

Comment: @ishtyaq-haider-jafri : Did you used the code provided in the answer ? Can you please update your question with new code

Comment: whatever line of code i wrot ein awake from nib have been removed and the  lines you suggested i worte them but then i am getting that image[2] and i want image [1] @SandeepBhandari

Comment: @ishtyaq-haider-jafri: Can you try using `layoutSubviews` rather than `awakeFromNib`

Comment: i have done the same    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    } then  override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
       let shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: 5)
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 10)
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        self.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.cgPath
    }@SandeepBhandari

Comment: @ishtyaq-haider-jafri : testing gimme a minute

Comment: @ishtyaq-haider-jafri : very strange tested your code works absolutely fine. Is the shadow looks fine after second cell ??

Comment: i am also using the same code let me try it on a raw project and will revert you @SandeepBhandari